# Cakephp 1.2 page goes white on any form submission

Tags: cakephp, memcached, cakephp-1.2, browser-cache

I have a local cakephp 1.2 app which was working fine last night.  Currently when I submit any form, the resulting page goes white/blank.

This is what I have tried:

- Cleared browser cache
- Commented out my memcache in core.php
- Turn debug on to 2, in which I get a couple of warnings (always had
  them), but no errors and the sql debug stuff
- Cleaned out cache of models and persistence in tmp folder
- also played with setting security from medium to low

Any ideas would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep that debug mode at 2 while developing. That helps a lot.

What are the warnings? If the code is correct, there shouldn't be any warnings. I don't think it's a problem with browser or cache. What's in your controller method? You can also do a $this->log($variable,'logfile') anywhere to debug. The output will be in tmp/log

Maybe you should upgrade to 1.3, I'm not sure if all my advises would work with 1.2

Comment: The warnings I get are only this: Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\review\cake\basics.php:108)

Comment: It's like the form submissions and redirects are failing.

Comment: and just like that it's back...all i did was put $this->log($variable,'logfile'); in my controller and it appears to be back online

Comment: whitespace after the `?>`? :)